# How to add attachment on FB with sharer.php?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, fbsdksharedialog

I'm trying figure if it possible to add attachment like **(@facebookGroupPage)** in a share dialog via **SHARER.PHP**,

tried to use `quote=blablabla @page`
but the attachment did NOT work.

BTW, with feed share i couldn't find if it possible too.

Comment: what do you mean? prefilling the message?

Comment: yes,
i want to add a share button on my platform, that will generate a share dialog that will include a text with an attachment to the platform on facebook.

example:

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.google.com&quote=visit%20here%20@Google`

Comment: ok, because that´s forbidden (and not possible anyway). you MUST read the platform policy.